# Powershell script repeats same server multiple times

Tags: powershell

I have a script that runs through servers and prints out if they can connect to specific ports or not. The problem seems to be that it keeps on looping through existing servers its already done...hence I see multiple servers results and the CSV file keeps on getting re-written as each iteration restarts the cycle again to add on the next server.

Any ideas on ensuring it just cycles through one server at a time and not repeating the same server each time? The end CSV is fine as it contains the total servers but its taking ages to get there.

Output is below - you can see how it keeps on re-doing exisitng servers and just adding on one server more each time it runs:

```
Destination    Port 3389 Port 445 Port 80
-----------    --------- -------- -------
10.104.122.21  Failure   Failure  Failure
10.104.122.50  Failure   Failure  Failure
10.104.125.237 Failure   Failure  Failure



Destination    Port 3389 Port 445 Port 80
-----------    --------- -------- -------
10.104.122.21  Failure   Failure  Failure
10.104.122.50  Failure   Failure  Failure
10.104.125.237 Failure   Failure  Failure
10.104.125.66  Failure   Failure  Failure



Destination    Port 3389 Port 445 Port 80
-----------    --------- -------- -------
10.104.122.21  Failure   Failure  Failure
10.104.122.50  Failure   Failure  Failure
10.104.125.237 Failure   Failure  Failure
10.104.125.66  Failure   Failure  Failure
10.104.125.95  Failure   Failure  Failure
```

The code is below:

```
Function Test-PortConnections {
    [CmdletBinding()]

    # Parameters used in this function
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory = $True, HelpMessage="Provide destination source", ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $Destination,

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory = $False, HelpMessage="Provide port numbers", ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $Ports = "80"
    ) 

    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    $Results = @()

    ForEach($D in $Destination){
        # Create a custom object
        $Object = New-Object PSCustomObject
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Destination" -Value $D

        Write-Verbose "Checking $D"
        ForEach ($P in $Ports){
                #write-host "Port is $p"
                $timeout=100
                $requestCallback = $state = $null
                $client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
                $beginConnect = $client.BeginConnect($d,$p,$requestCallback,$state)
                Start-Sleep -milli $timeOut
                if ($client.Connected -eq "True") { $Result = "True" } else { $Result = "False" }
                    $client.Close()
                        If($Result -eq "False"){ $status = "Failure" } else { $status = "Success" }

            $Object | Add-Member Noteproperty "$("Port " + "$p")" -Value "$($status)"
        }

        $Results += $Object

If($Results){
    $date = $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
    $Results | Format-Table -AutoSize
    $Results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," -Path H:\MyDocuments\Scripts\server_check_$($date).csv
}
}
} 

Test-PortConnections -Destination (Get-Content -Path "H:\MyDocuments\Scripts\servers.txt") -Ports 3389,445,80
```

Comment: It does not, but you keep writing all the previous results to the screen on each interation with `$Results | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it does - that line, when taken out correctly shows nothing on the screen but the CSV keeps on changing size. I can't show it here but the size keeps on changing from 1KB to 0KB then 2KB and then 0KB etc...which implies its definitely looping through multiple times on the same server again and again.

Comment: Yes, because you keep accummulating results and overwriting the same file with the new total set of results :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Yes, your right - I think I have fixed this now by moving the end bracket for the "Foreach" above the $date and that seems to have fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the outer `foreach()` loop runs, at the end you:

1. Add current object to existing results (`$Results += $object`)
2. Format and write *ALL* existing results to the screen (`$Results | Format-Table -AutoSize`)
3. Export *ALL* the existing results to file (`$Results | Export-Csv ...`)

`Export-Csv` will simply overwrite the previously written file, so there you won't see a difference in the final result.

To fix this, I'd suggest simply having your function output `$object` on its own as soon as you reach the end of the loop body, and then either move the `Export-Csv` step outside the loop:

```bsh
ForEach ($D in $Destination) {
    # Create a custom object
    $Object = New-Object PSCustomObject
    $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Destination" -Value $D

    Write-Verbose "Checking $D"
    ForEach ($P in $Ports) {
        #write-host "Port is $p"
        $timeout = 100
        $requestCallback = $state = $null
        $client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
        $beginConnect = $client.BeginConnect($d, $p, $requestCallback, $state)
        Start-Sleep -milli $timeOut
        if ($client.Connected -eq "True") { $Result = "True" } else { $Result = "False" }
        $client.Close()
        If ($Result -eq "False") { $status = "Failure" } else { $status = "Success" }

        $Object | Add-Member Noteproperty "$("Port " + "$p")" -Value "$($status)"
    }

    Write-Output $Object
    $Results += $object
}

If ($Results) {
    $date = $(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
    $Results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," -Path H:\MyDocuments\Scripts\server_check_$($date).csv
}
```

...or use `Export-Csv` with `-Append`, at which point you don't need `$Results` at all:

```bsh
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$ExportFileName = 'H:\MyDocuments\Scripts\server_check_${date}.csv'

ForEach ($D in $Destination) {
    # Create a custom object
    $Object = New-Object PSCustomObject
    $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Destination" -Value $D

    Write-Verbose "Checking $D"
    ForEach ($P in $Ports) {
        #write-host "Port is $p"
        $timeout = 100
        $requestCallback = $state = $null
        $client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
        $beginConnect = $client.BeginConnect($d, $p, $requestCallback, $state)
        Start-Sleep -milli $timeOut
        if ($client.Connected -eq "True") { $Result = "True" } else { $Result = "False" }
        $client.Close()
        If ($Result -eq "False") { $status = "Failure" } else { $status = "Success" }

        $Object | Add-Member Noteproperty "$("Port " + "$p")" -Value "$($status)"
    }

    Write-Output $object
    $object | Export-Csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," -Path $ExportFileName
}
```

Comment: Forgot all about -append! Thanks for that - it fixes the issue.